# Python Ray Cluster, tell Node A to never take LAST Task in Job

Tags: python, ray

I have a 3 node cluster for Ray.

Node A - 1 cpu

Node B - 1 cpu

Node C - 1 cpu

And 25 tasks.  If all things were equal, then A,B,C runs roughly 8 tasks and the last one is picked up by whoever finishes first.

However, I have found that the CPU on Node B is extremely slow!
Since Ray schedules jobs as resources becomes available, it just means that Node B will naturally process fewer tasks.  This is fine until we get to the last 1 or last 2 tasks.
If B picks up the last 1 or 2nd to last task, it will extend my runtime (as defined by completion of all 25 jobs) drastically.  It is literally faster for me to wait for A or C to become available and have A or C pick up the task when it can.

How can I set things up with Ray to do so?

I am using:
Python 3.10.12

Ray 2.7.0

By my understanding of CPU-resources, I cannot simply set the Job to require more CPU resources than what Node B offers.
In a round-about way, is it possible for me to check if there is only 1 or 2 tasks left in the queue and then change the CPU requirement for the last 1 or 2 task, so that Node B is rejected?

Am also open checking out suggested keywords and tips on checking out how to write Schedulers (top level look-over didn't seem like this was trivial?)

Comment: Since node b has lower task processing capabilities, why not set its logical CPU count to be lower when joining the cluster?